# How do I stop the monkey madness?

Tags: android, testing

I'm using the monkey tool to run a test of my Android application.  For example, I might do a run like the following:

```
adb shell monkey -p com.myapp -v 10000
```

However, if I change my mind and need to cancel the test, there doesn't seem to be a way to do so that doesn't involve waiting multiple minutes for the damned monkey to finish most or all of its run.

Killing the `adb shell` process on my mac doesn't solve the problem.  Killing the `com.myapp` process on my phone using ddms doesn't work.  Unplugging my phone doesn't work.

How do I cancel the monkey madness?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can kill the monkey process just doing this:

```
$ adb shell ps | awk '/com\.android\.commands\.monkey/ { system("adb shell kill " $2) }'
```

Comment: system("./adb shell kill " $2)

Comment: @RahulRastogi "didn't work" is not enough to understand your problem

Comment: I am using `adb shell kill $(pgrep monkey)`

Answer (score 16):

[Nitpick] You're confusing [monkeyrunner](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/monkeyrunner_concepts.html) with [monkey](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/monkey.html).

> The monkeyrunner tool is not related to the UI/Application Exerciser
>   Monkey, also known as the monkey tool. The monkey tool runs in an adb
>   shell directly on the device or emulator and generates pseudo-random
>   streams of user and system events. In comparison, the monkeyrunner
>   tool controls devices and emulators from a workstation by sending
>   specific commands and events from an API.

[/Nitpick]

On my Android 2.2 device when I start monkey, I see a process started in DDMS by the name "?" (just a question mark). When I killed that process, the monkey madness stopped.

Answer (score 9):

```
adb shell
ps | grep monkey
kill process_id
```

Comment: the process_id referred to in the kill statement is the first number returned by the "ps | grep monkey" command - that would be necessary to know

Answer (score 3):

```
adb shell kill $(adb shell pgrep monkey)
```

kudo to @deadfish

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, I use Android Studio 3.1.4 on a Mac in 2018 and I had to alter the accepted answer like so:

```
./adb shell ps | awk '/com\.android\.commands\.monkey/ { system("./adb shell kill " $2) }'
```

Hope that help prevent some hair-pulling and pencil snapping out there!

Also... when it comes to the monkey, always be sure to [pin](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/6118421?hl=en) your app!!! Otherwise you might accidentally send all your selfies to a random email in China like I did.  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

Kill the monkey by shell will cause a small problem, the IActivityController in ActivityTaskManagerService will not be set to null, which it should. And the ActivityManager.isUserAMonkey() still return true.

If monkey stop automatically, it will reset the Controller properly：

```
Monkey.java{
    private int run(String[] args) {
        ...
        try {
            mAm.setActivityController(null, true);
            mNetworkMonitor.unregister(mAm);
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add a little more detail? Where should this be run? All other answers suggest shell commands while this is a Java snippet.

Comment: When the monkey start, ActivityTaskManagerService init ActivityController, set mControllerIsAMonkey true.

Comment: Obviously, when monkey stop will set null and false, except monkey killed.Maybe is a bug ╮(─▽─)╭. I am using shell commands too.Bug I modify the ActivityTaskManagerService.isControllerAMonkey() to fix it.