# Killing android monkey process via adb only

Tags: android, adb, monkey

I have a problem with a monkey process. Starting Monkey is easy, but how to stop it? 
I know how to stop any process, but I have no idea how the monkey process is called. 
DDMS shows a "?" process, and that's it, but I have to kill it with an adb command.

Any idea?

Comment: Throw your phone at a brick wall.  That should do it..

Answer (score 3):

Command :

```
adb shell ps | awk '/com\.android\.commands\.monkey/ { system("adb shell kill " $2) }'
```

worked on android 2.3

Answer (score 1):

1. Do  adb shell ps
2. Search for process name monkey. note down pid of the monkey process
   (pidvalue)
3. adb shell kill *pidvalue*.   - where *pidvalue* is pid of monkey
   process.

That's all. monkey runner is stopped.

Answer (score 0):

Just run it with a set number of events:

```
$ adb shell monkey -p your.package.name -v NUMEVENTS
```

If you didn't know what you were getting into and ran monkey with a silly number of events (anything with > 3 zeros), you can kill it as described by both the answers in [how do I stop the monkey madness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999036/how-do-i-stop-the-monkey-madness)!

Comment: There is no answer for my question, or i may not understand you. sory for that.
Just like i said, i dont know how monkey process is called.
I have Windows system, ddms is not a solution for me
And console doesnt see com.android.commands.monkey process

Comment: What do you mean `ddms` is not a solution?  It's included with the SDK.  If you have `monkey` and `adb` you should have ddms..

Comment: I need to kill monkey only by adb cmd. I know i can do this by DDMS, but i need only adb command

Comment: Then why haven't you tried using the `adb` command in the linked solution:
`$ adb shell ps | awk '/com\.android\.commands\.monkey/ { system("adb shell kill " $2) }'`

Comment: ddms is not a solution for me And console doesnt see com.android.commands.monkey process.
That's what i wrote yesterday. I tried

Comment: So what processes *are* running when you list them with `adb`? It might have changed to something very similar... you should check rather than just floundering around..

Answer (score 0):

On an emulator with Android 2.2 the monkey process is called 'app_process'.
You can stop it with

```
adb shell ps | awk '/app\_process/ { system("adb shell kill -9 " $2) }'
```