# How to use monkey and monkeyrunner tools for android testing?

Tags: android, monkeyrunner, monkey

How do you use `monkey` and `monkeyrunner` tools for android testing?

What are the basic commands needed?

Answer (score 28):

```
adb shell monkey -p com.bla.yourpackage -v 1000
```

First is your package that you want monkey to run in and be restricted to.  Second is i verbose mode, third is number of events to run.

You can find out more by doing `adb shell monkey -help`

Answer (score 8):

Here are some useful tips when using monkey test.

### Specify one activity

Add `category` in manifest:

```
<activity android:name="MonkeyActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.MONKEY" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

and use command like this:

```
adb shell monkey -p my.package -c android.intent.category.MONKEY -v 500
```

### Prevent notification disturb

In Android 5.0+ you can use the feature Screen Pinning.

- open this feature in "settings" > "security" > "screen pinning"
- click recent/multitasking button beside home button
- click the green pin icon to pin the Application you want to test

then run your monkey test.

### stop monkeyTest

Use the following command to stop monkey test:

```
adb shell ps | awk '/com\.android\.commands\.monkey/ { system("adb shell kill " $2) }'
```

### reference

- [Android monkey test choose a specific activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16019290/android-monkey-test-choose-a-specific-activity)
- [How do I stop the monkey madness?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999036/how-do-i-stop-the-monkey-madness)

Answer (score 6):

`monkey` and `monkeyrunner` are different tools.

**Monkey**

You can run `monkey` from `adb shell`, then it will generate pseudo-random streams of user events. You can specify some conditions and constraints for the execution of these events (see [documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkey.html))

> The basic syntax is:

> `$ adb shell monkey [options] <event-count>`

**Monkeyrunner**

`monkeyrunner` is an API to control an Android device or emulator from outside of Android code, as the documentation defines. You can basically write Python scripts that describes some actions to be executed on target device.

[Sample Program](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkeyrunner_concepts.html#SampleProgram)

Quoting Android Developers [documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkeyrunner_concepts.html):

> The monkeyrunner tool is not related to the UI/Application Exerciser
> Monkey, also known as the `monkey` tool. The `monkey` tool runs in an `adb`
> shell directly on the device or emulator and generates pseudo-random
> streams of user and system events. In comparison, the monkeyrunner
> tool controls devices and emulators from a workstation by sending
> specific commands and events from an API.

Answer (score 1):

These three steps should help you set it up:

1 ) Get inside this directory - `~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools`

2) Start server - `./adb start-server`

3) Command to test 5000 random keystrokes in your app - `./adb shell monkey -p your.package.name -v 500`

For more information check this out. 
https://developer.android.com/studio/test/monkey.html