# How do I force stop a monkey automation?

Tags: android, monkey

I've followed this [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/monkey.html) by letting it do 100,000 events. Now, I don't know how do I stop this thing aside from restarting the emulator.

Thank you.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999036/how-do-i-stop-the-monkey-madness.

Comment: awk' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: The command works for me