# How do you stop a Monkeyrunner script?

Tags: android, adb, monkeyrunner

I was experimenting with a Monkeyrunner script which repeated some touch actions 100 times. After noticing a bug, I wanted to stop the script, but didn't find any tools to do this. I tried to kill the `com.android.commands.monkey` process via adb, but when I executed `adb shell ps`, the process appeared again. Unplugging the phone from my computer didn't work either, as the script seems to run on the phone without the computer as well.

**Are there any tools to stop an already executed Monkeyrunner script?**

Comment: Have you tried with `Ctrl + C` to stop the script?

Comment: thank you, this seems to work

Comment: Are you talking about monkey or monkeyrunner, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999036/how-do-i-stop-the-monkey-madness?

Comment: I'm talking about Monkeyrunner.