# kill Android application launched with Monkey without root permissions

Tags: android, adb, monkey

I am using Monkey to take measurements on an Android device. I launch a series of applications and after a certain amount of time I should kill one. Is it possible to do this without unlocking the root permissions on the smartphone?
I've tried several commands, including:

```
adb shell am force-stop com.samsung.android.calendar

adb shell am kill com.samsung.android.calendar
```

Unfortunately these commands don't work or maybe they work on the spot, but after a few seconds Monkey relaunches the application.
I found other commands that however require you to unlock the root permissions on the smartphone, which I should avoid.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/10002312/236465

Comment: If monkey restarts the app then you should first stop monkey and then the app.

Comment: @Robert I can't stop Monkey because it has to generate the series of events set by the seed. If I stop it and then restart it, it generates a series from the beginning.

Comment: Sorry but then your question is unclear what you actually want to do. Please describe why you want to stop the app but keep monkey running. I don't see any sense in doing so.

Comment: @Robert I launch 10 user apps with Monkey to take measurements. After a certain amount of time, I have to kill an app to measure the impact that app has on performance degradation. Out of 10 applications, I only have to kill one, while the other 9 must continue to be launched by Monkey.

Comment: You didn't show how you start the 10 apps? 1 monkey? 10 monkeys?